# textDirection != null assert is not null ListTile

Tags: flutter

When using `ListTile` in `Material` widget, the flutter app is stuck on error saying `"Failed assertion: line 507 pos 15 'textDirection != null' assert is not true"`. But the ListItem widget does not have any property as `textDirection`. How do I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the ListItem widget?

Comment: Sorry it was `ListTile`

Comment: ok, could you paste your code to check the error?

Comment: I have updated the question with code and error screenshot

Comment: actually you don't need to specify the textDirection on Text widget, could you remove those ?

Comment: another question, what version of flutter are you using?

Comment: Okay, I have removed the `textDirection` property from `Text` widget and will the flutter version be in `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: no, just run the command : flutter --version

Comment: Flutter 1.0.0
Dart: 2.1.0

Comment: Its weird, does it works without textDirectiom ?

Comment: The `Text` widget does not work without the `textDirection` property
The `ListTile` is also not working without it but there is no such property for `ListTile`

Answer (score 6):

I saw the error, it happens when you don't have a `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp` as initial Widget, I suggest you to create a new project and see how Flutter creates the `Widgets`.

To fix your issue :

```
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: ListTile(
            ...
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

`textDirection` is not required

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Flex and adding `direction: Axis.vertical` fix it for me.